# Alexa Skill not appearing on US store, only visible on UK store. Why does this happen?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I published an Alexa skill for all the stores. US, UK, CA, IN. But only the UK store shows it live, why not the other stores?

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B077L6KVMF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon play around with the search results and hide things you'd expect to see in my experience. Some of my skills aren't visible to me in non-UK Amazon sites but they are there....

This skill is in the US store for example:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B077L6KVMF/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077L6KVMF)

Check the Metrics for the skill and see which geographies are enabling your skill, you should find it's not just UK.

Executive summary: Don't sweat it :)